# What is an empty constraint useful for?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In Haskell it is absolutely legal to write

```
f :: () => Int -> Int
```

Or even

```
f :: (Num i, ()) => i -> i
```

Why is this `()` allowed? To me it looks like it brought no information, but since it is valid syntax, I guess there are cases where it comes useful.

Comment: You can define a tuple of constraints and then reuse this as an alias. So it is not per se known at that time if it is an empty tuple.

Comment: See https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constraint_kind.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The empty constraint can be useful in type aliases and type families that produce constraints. For instance, here's a contrived example.

```
type family F :: Type -> Constraint where
   F (a -> b) = ()
   F a        = (Show a, Read a)
```

Then, `foo :: F t => ...` would only require `Show` and `Read` on non-function types. Combined with GADTs / singletons, it can be exploited to create type-level machinery.

One could write a trivial constraint instead of `()`, like `Num Int` or `Bool ~ Bool`, but using a special syntax like `()` better expresses the intent.

Answer (score 5):

When you get into extensions such as `ConstraintKinds` and `TypeFamilies`, then constraints can be *computed*, not just statically listed.

As such, there are times when an interface requires you to provide something of kind `Constraint`, but you may not need any actual constraint. You then need a way of representing an "empty" constraint; one that imposes no actual requirements (and also grants no additional power when it holds), but is nevertheless a thing of kind `Constraint`. Given that we can combine multiple constraints into a single item of kind `Constraint` by writing `(C1, C2, C3, ...)`, then the obvious syntax for an empty constraint is `()`. (In exactly the same way we get `()` as the syntax for "unit", which can be interpreted as an "empty tuple")

Given that `()` is a valid thing with kind `Constraint`, you can use it anywhere something with kind `Constraint` is required. That includes as one member of a tuple of constraints on a type signature, like `foo :: (EQ a, ()) => ...`. It also includes as the *entirety* of the constraints, like `bar :: () => ...`. It's not *useful* to do so but it's perfectly clear what it means, by all the same rules as apply to any other `Constraint`.

In general, you make an understandable programming language by carefully thinking out the rules such that any possible combination of them is meaningful, and then rigidly sticking to them as much as possible. Trying to add more and more special cases to rule out "useless" uses of particular features is a never ending task, makes everyone using the system have to memorise all the special cases as well as the normal rules, and sooner or later someone is bound to come up with a context you didn't think of where actually the "useless" thing isn't useless after all. And only a **miniscule** proportion of all the "useless" code that can be written could ever hope to be detected by trivial syntactic rules like "in a type signature left of the `=>` you can write any constraint except `()`". So generally, programming language designers need a very good reason to *forbid* something like empty constraints; asking for why something like that is *allowed* frequently just has the boring answer: "why not?"

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the [**`ConstraintKinds`** extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constraint_kind.html#extension-ConstraintKinds) to define aliases for constraints, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type Foo a = (Num a, Ord a)

myFun :: Foo a => a -> Bool
myFun = (0 <)
```

But it is thus not known per se how many constraints you will list. It thus accepts tuples of any arity, since the number of constraints can be zero, one, or more.